# Print automatically printable streams

Tags: java, pdf, printing, vbscript

I am looking for a way to print printable outputs rendered by an application.

An example to be more explicit :

Say we have an application "A" that allows us to print an output.

What I want to automate is :

1. Detect that "A" is opened and provides an output that can be
   printed
2. Go to File -> Print
3. choose a PDF printer (Adobe, PDF creator)
4. choose the output file name and save it.

I am on Windows XP.

Thank you in advance,

Aminsky

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

1. Install system-wide hook to detect that "A" is opened. I successfully used [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this in the past.
2. Analyze windows contents (probably analyze window title)
3. Prepare printer DC for a PDF printer in your application
4. Call [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to cause "A" to print it's window contents to PDF printer.

Please note that not all (but many) applications will properly handle PrintWindow calls.

Comment: @Aminsky No, I have no code which I am ready to share. And, btw, you might want to specify preferred languages in a question next time.